# Iterate over table of objects in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

How should I iterate over a table of objects like this?

```
CREATE TYPE SOME_OBJECT AS OBJECT (
  ATTR1 VARCHAR2(20)
, ATTR2 VARCHAR2(30)
);
/

CREATE TYPE C_SOME_OBJECT AS TABLE OF SOME_OBJECT;
/
```

And... I want to use this as a parameter for a procedure. Have to initialize it in procedure?

```
PROCEDURE SOME_PROCEDURE(OBJECT IN C_SOME_OBJECT)
IS
BEGIN
  --Some code here iterating IN parameter
END;
```

Comment: Surely if it's passed into the procedure, it's already initialised.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
-- NOTE #1
-- You cant use Object as name for your input variable because it is a type
-- (Types are reserved words)
PROCEDURE SOME_PROCEDURE(p_SOME_TABLE IN C_SOME_OBJECT)
IS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN p_SOME_TABLE.FIRST .. p_SOME_TABLE.LAST
  LOOP
     -- NOTE #2 Manage it like this
     -- Current iteration: p_SOME_TABLE(i)
     -- Access Example   : p_SOME_TABLE(i).ATTR1

     -- NOTE #3 Or you can assign current iteration to a variable
     -- then use that variable thought it is not by reference if you
     -- do it like this.
  END LOOP;
END;
```

**UPDATE:**

Also be careful not to confuse RECORDS with OBJECTS.

An OBJECT is an SQL type but RECORD on the other hand is a PL/SQL type, you could think of it more of a C/C++ like struct.

**UPDATE_2:**

Note that this wont raise any exception if the table is empty thus you need to handle if there are no data, for example you could use .COUNT like this:

```
IF p_SOME_TABLE.COUNT = 0 THEN
   RAISE my_exception;
END IF;
```

Comment: @Rancio This will not handle sparse collections where an item has been deleted and will throw an exception if an element of the collection is null.

Comment: @MT0 That is actually interesting, i always pass data with indexes in even though they have null detail values. I mean you can count this as a very special occasion. Because most of the time you pass structs that contain data with a reference to an index or key value, you don't just trust the series that they are passed in. A solution might be infinitely looping and break on count, but that just sounds risky programming.

Comment: @KALALEX You can set the attributes of an initialised object in an array element to `NULL` and that is fine - but you can also set the array element to `NULL` using `p_some_table(1) := NULL;` (or just by not initialising that element) in which case using `p_some_table(1).attr1` will raise an exception and your code will fail. And, no don't use an infinite loop - just use a `WHILE` loop with `i := p_some_table.NEXT(i);` to get the next index.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `WHILE` loop with `FIRST`, `NEXT`, `LAST` to handle sparse collections (where elements have been deleted) and you also need to check for uninitialised elements in the collection:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE SOME_PROCEDURE(
  I_OBJECT IN C_SOME_OBJECT
)
IS
  i PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  -- Check that the collection is not NULL
  IF I_OBJECT IS NULL THEN
    RETURN;
  END IF;

  i := I_OBJECT.FIRST;
  WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
    IF I_OBJECT(i) IS NOT NULL THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( i || ' = (' || I_OBJECT(i).attr1 || ', ' || I_OBJECT(i).attr2 || ')' );
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( i || ' IS NULL' );
    END IF;
    i := I_OBJECT.NEXT(i);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then you can call it:

```sql
DECLARE
  o C_SOME_OBJECT := C_SOME_OBJECT(
                       SOME_OBJECT( '1.1', '1.2' ),
                       SOME_OBJECT( '2.1', '2.2' ),
                       NULL,
                       SOME_OBJECT( '4.1', '4.2' )
                     );
BEGIN
  o.DELETE(2);

  SOME_PROCEDURE( o );
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 1 = (1.1, 1.2)
> 3 IS NULL
> 4 = (4.1, 4.2)
> ```

#### Issues with `FOR ... LOOP`:

Using `FOR i IN 1 .. o.COUNT LOOP`:

```sql
DECLARE
  o C_SOME_OBJECT := C_SOME_OBJECT(
                       SOME_OBJECT( '1.1', '1.2' ),
                       SOME_OBJECT( '2.1', '2.2' ),
                       NULL,
                       SOME_OBJECT( '4.1', '4.2' )
                     );
BEGIN
  o.DELETE(2);

  FOR i IN 1 .. o.COUNT LOOP
    IF o(i) IS NOT NULL THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( i || ' = (' || o(i).attr1 || ', ' || o(i).attr2 || ')' );
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( i || ' IS NULL' );
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Does not run and raises the exception:

> ```
> ORA-01403: no data found
> ORA-06512: at line 12
> ```

Because it reaches the second item in the array and tries to read it but it has been deleted and no data is found.

If the exception is caught:

```sql
DECLARE
  o C_SOME_OBJECT := C_SOME_OBJECT(
                       SOME_OBJECT( '1.1', '1.2' ),
                       SOME_OBJECT( '2.1', '2.2' ),
                       NULL,
                       SOME_OBJECT( '4.1', '4.2' )
                     );
BEGIN
  o.DELETE(2);

  FOR i IN 1 .. o.COUNT LOOP
    BEGIN
      IF o(i) IS NOT NULL THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( i || ' = (' || o(i).attr1 || ', ' || o(i).attr2 || ')' );
      ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( i || ' IS NULL' );
      END IF;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( i || ' NOT FOUND' );
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then the output is:

> ```
> 1 = (1.1, 1.2)
> 2 NOT FOUND
> 3 IS NULL
> ```

This outputs element 2, which does not exist, and does not output element 4, which does exist.

Using `FOR i IN o.FIRST .. o.LAST LOOP`:

```sql
DECLARE
  o C_SOME_OBJECT := C_SOME_OBJECT(
                       SOME_OBJECT( '1.1', '1.2' ),
                       SOME_OBJECT( '2.1', '2.2' ),
                       NULL,
                       SOME_OBJECT( '4.1', '4.2' )
                     );
BEGIN
  o.DELETE(2);

  FOR i IN o.FIRST .. o.LAST LOOP
    BEGIN
      IF o(i) IS NOT NULL THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( i || ' = (' || o(i).attr1 || ', ' || o(i).attr2 || ')' );
      ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( i || ' IS NULL' );
      END IF;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( i || ' NOT FOUND' );
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 1 = (1.1, 1.2)
> 2 NOT FOUND
> 3 IS NULL
> 4 = (4.1, 4.2)
> ```

This outputs 4 elements (including the deleted 2nd element) when `o.COUNT` is only 3; meaning that the code is doing extra, unnecessary processing.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9bc4480652b29772a16a8d97724bb9c7)*

Comment: In the first example a call to i := I_OBJECT.NEXT(i) is missing, this will cause an endless loop